# SSIS pivot issues

Tags: ssis, pivot

I have the following data

```
Col1,  Col2,  Col3, Col4, Col5                         
1, P,  W, M, adhfggh                 
1, P,  W, M, fdasdfd                    
1, P,  W, M, retretre
```

So, I would like to get this

```
Col1,  Col2,  Col3, Col4, ColA, ColB, ColC         
1, P,  W, M, adhfggh, fdasdfd, retretre
```

I could not figure out how to do this using SSIS.

I should try something like this using SQL statements, but not sure what to put in brackets

```
select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from tableA         
Unpivot 
( Col5 for Col5 in (, , ) ) as UnPvt
```

Comment: Can you add code snippets of what you already tried so far?

Comment: I am pretty new to SSIS... So, I realized I can not do it via Pivot transformation or via SQL query (Data Source) .